# Identify variable name based on value

Tags: sas

I have a value and I need to find what are the variables in a dataset has this value. All are character variables and search value is also character variable.

Example:

Value to be searched:**123456**

[image: dataset and search value]

Output: Var1 and Var3

- All variables are character
- this is sample dataset: in reality there are hundreds of variables to be searched

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post sample data as text. To work with your code I'd have to type it out and that's not going to happen. You also need to post what you've tried and what you want as output. What happens if it's found multiple times, is that possible? What if it's not found?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be: "Var2 and Var3" ?

Comment: Search value: 123456
Dataset:
var1       var2        var3
14789    233654   123456
233645  123456   14789

Yes you are right. Typo error: the output should be var2 and var3

I have not tried any method so far, since I dont have the idea of how to do it . the real dataset has 150 variables and the observation count is in thousands. I dont want to do a proc freq on every variable and search for this value. 

Thanks

Comment: @MikeA if you happen to read this question again: the tag is [tag:sas] which is presumably the format of the dataset (a SAS dataset).

Comment: if the value is found in more than one variable, I want all the variable list that has this value. 

if the value is not found in any of the variables list, then the output should be missing

Comment: @ManiPrakashT You're generally expected to have made some attempt on your own prior to coming here.  I don't mind answering when there's a specific function that does precisely what you want, but in general you should do some research of your own.  It sounds like the clarification suggests my answer doesn't completely help you; but a relatively simple search on using arrays in SAS would be all that you'd need to solve this, without coming here.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use `WHICHC` in conjunction with an array, and then `VNAME` to find out the name of the variable.

```
data have;
input x $ y $ z $;
datalines;
123456 234567 345678
234567 345678 123456
345678 234567 456789
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array vars x y z;
  pos = whichc('123456',of vars[*]);
  if pos>0 then varname = vname(vars[pos]);
run;
```

`WHICHC` returns 0 if not found.  Then you could use `PROC FREQ` on this dataset to find the list of all values that have this.

This particular approach only works if it can only exist once per row; if it can exist in two variables on the same row, you would have to loop over the array and search it iteratively.

Comment: Thanks Joe, this is what exactly I want. Thanks for the help